# How to create a Facebook Like with a post/comment box

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I am attempting to add a Facebook [*like* button](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Like_button) *with* a comment box to a site. When you click the *like* button you will be like the Facebook page itself, that is, `Facebook.com/thesitesname`. Where can I find a good starter example that will allow this to work?

I am getting the *like* button but no comment box...

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>
        (function (d, s, id) {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) 
                return;
            js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=111116358987784";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        } (document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    </script>
<div class="fb-like" 
     data-href="http://www.facebook.com/ASITE" 
     data-send="false" 
     data-layout="box_count" 
     data-width="50" 
     data-show-faces="false" d
     ata-font="arial">
</div>
```

Comment: The comments functionality comes with the [comments plugin](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/) not the like plugin. Just use both plugins.

Comment: Is it not a comment then?  If you create and click a like button here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/ you get a post/comment box

Comment: When a user likes something using the like button a story appears on his wall/timeline and his friends will see it in their feed. The box that appears when you click the like button is for the user to add a personal message to this post on his wall. It's not a comment on the liked page, for that exists the comments plugin.

Comment: Ok, so it there something wrong with the code that I have in my post that cause the "personal message" box not to appear the way it does on the like page?

Comment: Do you also have the *"fb-like* div? Is the only problem that the message box doesn't appear?

Comment: yes, I do (dam Ctrl v) <fb:like href="http://www.facebook.com/asite" send="false" layout="box_count" width="50" show_faces="false" font="arial"></fb:like>. and yes for some reason no message box

Answer (score 1):

In the page for the [Like Button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/), the last question in the FAQ section:

> **When I click the Like button, the popup window (or "flyout") doesn't
>   show. Why?**
>
> If the Like button is placed near the edge of an HTML element with the
>   overflow property set to hidden, the flyout may be clipped or
>   completely hidden when the button is clicked. This can be remedied by
>   setting setting the overflow property to a value other than hidden,
>   such as visible, scroll, or auto.

Comment: I looked into any css issues, it appears the popup is not being triggered

Comment: No errors, when I inspect the element in Firebug nothing inside or outside the iFrame (aside from the button) changes

Comment: Can you post the url for the page in question?

Comment: I found my problem, it appears to be localhost that was causing the issues, strange because a separate wall post I have on the page works fine. Thanks for you help.